# How to predict a label in svm for real data?

Tags: matlab

my code is classifying the gender from real time video and i have used svm for classification..i expected to classify correctly by svm but it did not ..this is my code after i used dct for feature extraction  ,and i did anew model contain areal data captured by web camera to use in the prediction function called me2 model .. can i have some help please

sample= coefficent';

```
        training=X ;
        group = Y;
```

this is the model contain areal data captured by web camera

```
  load    me2.mat   
 Test3=XX;
     Y3=YY;
```

[ Y,X] = libsvmread('SPECTFlibsvm.train');
  model = svmtrain(Y,  X,'-c 16 -g 0.0156');

[predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(YY,XX,model); this line code does not work even though it does not give me any error message

```
         if predict_label==1
            x='Male';
        else
            x='Female';
         end
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly: indent code with 4 spaces, use upper case at the start of a sentence, ... It will make your question easier to read.

Comment: Looks like you are using the LibSVM in MATLAB.  Please consult the duplicate for an example of how to use it for classification.